# Place circle inside svg path

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a svg path defined like this :

```
<path d="M8080.74 4905.89L8083.56 4909.45L8178.70 4833.53L8176.16 
4830.33L8181.41 4826.17L8181.38 4826.13L8185.02 4823.20L8185.02 
4817.61L8189.07 4817.61L8189.07 4695.89L8185.02 4695.89L8185.02
4286.40L8185.02 4239.07L7991.62 4239.07L7991.62 4286.40L7963.22
4286.40L7963.22 4358.08L7963.22 4513.61L7963.22 4686.72L7768.53
4843.60L7635.93 4843.60L6965.13 4843.60L6955.67 4843.60L6955.67
4839.54L6835.30 4839.54L6835.30 4843.60L6468.80 4843.60L6468.80
4839.54L6345.73 4839.54L6345.73 4843.60L5983.28 4843.60L5983.28
4839.54L5860.21 4839.54L5860.21 4843.60L5853.45 4843.60L5804.76
4843.60L5802.06 4843.60L5756.07 4843.60L5753.37 4843.60L5746.61
4843.60L5746.61 4839.54L5623.54 4839.54L5623.54 4843.60L5139.37
4843.60L5139.37 4867.94L5139.37 4874.71L5132.61 4874.71L5132.61
4997.78L5139.37 4997.78L5139.37 5032.94L5615.42 5032.94L5622.18
5032.94L5622.18 5037.00L5745.25 5037.00L5745.25 5032.94L5756.07
5032.94L5802.06 5032.94L5804.76 5032.94L5853.45 5032.94L6522.89
5032.94L6529.66 5032.94L6529.66 5037.00L6652.73 5037.00L6652.73
5032.94L7508.81 5032.94L7508.81 5037.00L7631.88 5037.00L7631.88
5032.94L7924.23 5032.94z" stroke="#ff0000" fill="none" id="622754" />
```

I've done this by using getBBox() and calculate the center of ths path, but it returns a square around the path, so my circle is outside.

I have to calculate the coordinates of the circle dynamically as this is building plan. Of course, I have many building plans and paths with special forms like this.

How can I draw my circle inside the path ?

EDIT :

The svg looks like this : 
[image: svg][Imgur]

I need to draw a svg circle inside this path. The circle in red should be in the place below.

Here's how I calculate the coordinates of the point : 

`let locPosition = (localisation as any).getBBox(); // This is the BBox of the path -> {x: 5132.60986328125, y: 4239.06982421875, width: 3056.4599609375, height: 797.93017578125})
let centerX = locPosition.x + locPosition.width / 2;
let centerY = locPosition.y + locPosition.height / 2;`

Here's a link to a fiddle that contains the path and the circle : 
https://jsfiddle.net/etgyru5q/

What I want is the circle inside the path, in the middle of it.

Comment: Where's your getBBox code? It would be much easier if you supplied a picture of what this is supposed to look like, and if you wrapped the <path> with an <svg> element so it's valid and viewable.

Comment: what dou you mean by `draw my circle inside the path` punching a hole into the shape, or simply placing a circle on top of that path?

Comment: edited, thanks for replying, tell me if it's not clear enough

Comment: This is a mathematical problem of topology; you nead a better definition of what "the middle" means. SVG 2.0 has an interface `SVGGeometryElement.isPointInFill(DOMPoint)`, but it seems to be implemented only by Chrome yet.